# drawing lines but i don't see them on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

When i run this code, to try to draw a grid for a *snake* game:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')


class grid(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, width, x, y):
        self.rows = rows
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sizeBetween = width // rows

    def draw(self, surface):
        for l in range(self.rows):
            self.x += self.sizeBetween
            self.y += self.sizeBetween

            pygame.draw.line(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, 0), (self.x, self.width))
            pygame.draw.line(win, (255, 255, 255), (0, self.y), (self.width, self.y))


def window(surface):
    grid.draw(surface)

    pygame.display.update()


grid = grid(20, 500, 0, 0)
win = pygame.display.set_mode((grid.width, grid.width))
run = True
while run:
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window(win)
```

It doesn't draw any lines. I'm new to *pygame* and don't really know how to fix problems like this, since it will just open a black box without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid is only drawn for a short moment in the 1st frame, because the attributes `x` and `y` are incremented continuously, but never *reset*.

> ```py
> def draw(self, surface):
>    for l in range(self.rows):
>        self.x += self.sizeBetween
>        self.y += self.sizeBetween
> ```

In the 2nd frame, the display is cleared, but the current value of the attributes `x` and `y` is `self.rows * self.sizeBetween`. Hence all the lines are drawn out of the window.

Change the drawing of the grid:

```py
class Grid(object):
    # [...]

     def draw(self, surface):
        x, y = self.x, self.y 
        for l in range(self.rows-1):
            x += self.sizeBetween
            y += self.sizeBetween

            pygame.draw.line(surface, (255, 255, 255), (x, 0), (x, self.width))
            pygame.draw.line(surface, (255, 255, 255), (0, y), (self.width, y))
```

---

Side note, the name of the class `grid` and the instance `gird` are identical. This causes that the instance covers the class. Python is case sensitive and class names should normally use the CapWords convention. See [Style Guide for Python Code - Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

I recommend to change the name of the class:

```py
class Grid(object):
    # [...]

# [...]

grid = Grid(20, 500, 0, 0)
```